# Is there any way to make a vertical table with Tabulator?

Tags: tabulator

When I say "vertical table", I mean with headers down the left side and each set of data displayed as a column beyond that.

I tried changing the data so that rows are columns and vice versa, but ran into issues with formatting, as for example I couldn't see a way to apply number formatting to each row rather than to each column.

Comment: You could use a Custom Formatter http://tabulator.info/docs/4.9/format#format-custom and detect which row it's on, and return the data formatted appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Tabulator only allows for column headers along the top of the table. There is currently no plan to allow for column headers down the side of the table.